# PHP picking data from a string

Tags: php, api

Basically I am wondering how I would go about taking pieces of a string and putting them into another variable. I need to do this as, from API I am using, you are given the date of channel creation and I would like to take the data from this, but it is displayed in a strange way.

Here is what is given by the API:

```
2012-06-11T13:36:21Z seconds
```

^^ That is what I need to change so that I can display it in a nicer way. i.e. 11-06-2012.

Thanks.

P.S. This is twitch API if it matters.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php or http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Taking pieces of a string sounds like regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two PHP functions: "strtotime()" and "date()"

```
$timestamp = "2012-06-11T13:36:21Z";
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime($timestamp));
```

The above would echo "11th June, 2012"

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function for DateTime.